# Incomplete video streaming to mobile browsers - HTTP headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video, nancy

I am trying to stream mp4 (fragmented) video to a mobile browser client using Nancy MVC framework. Everything works fine. The code is enclosed.

The thing is, a video is going to generated simultaneously as being streamed, so the stream.Length will increase over period of time. ***Does someone knows what to do to support this scenario ?***

(I have tried to commit the length in "content-range" header, giving an arbitrary max size to encompass whole video size, but no avail...)

```
 /*called when /video is requested*/
Get["/video"] = _ => 
{
    if (Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("Range"))
      return Response.FromPartialStream(Request, File.OpenRead("../Page/video-fragmented.mp4"), "video/mp4");
    else
      /*from stream...*/
};

public static Response FromPartialStream(this IResponseFormatter f,
                                          Request req, Stream stream,
                                          string contentType)
{
    const string BYTES_RANGE_HEADER = "Range";

    if (req.Headers[BYTES_RANGE_HEADER].Count() != 1)
        throw new NotSupportedException();

    var rangeStr = req.Headers[BYTES_RANGE_HEADER].FirstOrDefault();
    var range = rangeStr.Replace("bytes=", String.Empty)
                        .Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x))
                        .ToArray();

    var start = (range.Length > 0) ? range[0] : 0;
    var end = (range.Length > 1) ? range[1] : (int)(stream.Length - 1);

    var res = new PartialStreamResponse(stream, start, end, contentType)
                  .WithHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
                  .WithHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                  .WithHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + stream.Length)
                  .WithHeader("Content-Length", (end - start + 1).ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("Requested range: {0}", rangeStr);
    return res;
}

public class PartialStreamResponse : Response
{
    Stream sourceStream = null;
    int start, end;

    public PartialStreamResponse(Stream sourceStream, int start, int end, string mimeType)
    {
        this.sourceStream = sourceStream;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        Contents = populateRequest;
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
        ContentType = mimeType;
    }

    private void populateRequest(Stream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin stream...");
        sourceStream.CopyTo(stream, start, end);
        Console.WriteLine("End stream");
    }
}
```

EDIT: serving such files should also work for mobile browsers (single file would be preferred over HLS or DASH which require segments)

Comment: How are you Hosting Nancy?  This will impact the solution.

Comment: I use self-hosting, but I can switch to Nancy + IIS or AP.NET MVC + IIS if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Well at least Chrome and Firefox happily handle `200 OK` responses without `Content-Range` or `Content-Length` headers in the response. In my opinion you should only reply with `206 Partial Content` if the request range has a valid end marker otherwise just reply with `200 OK` without a content length and push the stream. Of course another thing is how to handle the file being generated live. I'd advise having the `moov` part in a separate file and then generating a second file with the current `moof` - that way a new client would initially get the `moov` (which should be fixed) and when that data has been sent the server would just continue reading and serving the `moof` file, which will be refreshed. Also to escape I/O starvation (the server trying to read the file and whatever generates the content trying to write to it) you could have at least 2 `moof` files which act as a  double buffer - one is the last finished fragment and another is the one currently being written.

Here is an example of request/response headers a working live fragmented video in Chrome:

[image: Chrome request/response headers]

In my opinion the `206 Partial Content` responses are more useful for static video content than for live because in that case the browser can get the `moov` atom, parse all the size and offset tables and offer seeking while content is being loaded, which is not possible for a live video.

Comment: Many thanks! Will accept as soon as I check it (this thing has to work on mobile browsers as well....).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for mobile browsers.

Comment: Well, iOS does not support fMP4 at all (ok in the last WDDC they announced that they will support it), and Chrome seems to be picky (afaik Chrome did a range 0-1 request to or smth like that before the actual data and required some special atoms), but well that is the current situation - there is no bulletproof solution.

Comment: @dajuric I'm afraid you won't be able to handle all clients with a single pipeline. I'd say that you'll still have to have HLS + MP4.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple requests (one per fragment) or use chunked transfer.